# Approximating sums as integrals and divergent terms

Tags: statistical-mechanics, integration, many-body, approximations

I have the following sum (notice that the sum starts from 2, i.e. there's no divergence):

$$\sum_{i=2}^{N}C_i\dfrac{\exp{\left(-k| \mathbf{R}_i-\mathbf{R}_1| \right) }}{| \mathbf{R}_i-\mathbf{R}_1|}$$

Where $\mathbf{R}_i$ are vectors belonging to $\mathbb{R}^3$ and are enclosed in some volume $V$ (They represent the positions of some atoms).
$C_i$ is some well behaved function (we might aswell take it to be 1).

Now suppose I want to approximate this sum as an integral, in the limit where $N \rightarrow \infty$ and the atoms at position $\mathbf{R}_i$ are densely close to each other.
My tentative answer would be to write:
$$\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=2}^{N}C_i \dfrac{\exp{\left(-k| \mathbf{R}_i-\mathbf{R}_1| \right) }}{| \mathbf{R}_i-\mathbf{R}_1|} = \int_V d^3\mathbf{R}  \dfrac{\exp{\left(-k| \mathbf{R}-\mathbf{R_1}| \right) }}{| \mathbf{R}-\mathbf{R_1}|} \rho(\mathbf{R}) C(\mathbf{R})  $$
Where in this limit:

$\mathbf{R}:=\mathbf{R}_i$, and
$\rho(\mathbf{R})=\dfrac{N}{V}$

Is this in some way rigorous? I think it makes sense as I often saw a similar procedure in Statistical Mechanics.

Now, what about the term $\mathbf{R}_i=\mathbf{R}_1$? In the sum that term is divergent and is not included. But in the integral it is somewhat impossible to exclude it, and it doesn't give any problem as it's divergence seems to be cancelled by the integration in 3 variables.

Is there a way to convince myself that the error I'm making is negligible?

Comment: How are you determining the points $\mathbf{R}_i$? What exactly is happening as you take the limit as $N\rightarrow\infty$? I expect the answer is *probably*, that this will converge to the [Cauchy principle value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value) of the integral, (which is *probably* what you would have naively calculated anyway) but, depending on how rigorous you want to be, proving that may be quite painful

Comment: Here's the problem: the points $\mathbf{R_i}$ are an output in the calculation I'm making. I guess one can suppose they are at an equal distance one from another for the time being. Being particulary rigorous is not by itself a requirement, it's more about justifying the inclusion of the term $i=1$.
Regardins the Cauchy principle value: can I say that if the integral converges written like that, then it coincides with its principle value?

Comment: If the integral is convergent in the standard sense then it should agree with the CPV

Comment: Is there a way to express this continuum limit as the limit of a Riemann sum or as a consequence of Euler McLaurin theorem in order to get an estimate of the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a substitution $\mathbf R' = \mathbf R - \mathbf R_1$
$$\int_V d^3\mathbf{R}  \dfrac{\exp{\left(-k| \mathbf{R}-\mathbf{R_1}| \right) }}{| \mathbf{R}-\mathbf{R_1}|} \rho(\mathbf{R}) C(\mathbf{R}) = 
\int_{V'} d^3\mathbf{R'}  \dfrac{e^{-k| \mathbf{R}'| }}{| \mathbf{R}'|} \rho(\mathbf{R+\mathbf R_1}) C(\mathbf{R}+\mathbf R_1)$$

Let's now turn to polar coordinates *centered in* $\mathbf R_1$, with $r' = |\mathbf R'|$. It might now be quite hard to convert $\rho$ and $C$ to polar coordinates in this frame of reference, depending on the symmetries of your problem. If, as I suspect, $\rho$ is unknown and will be found using this integral, then you shouldn't have a problem. But I don't know, and I hope this helps anyway.

$$ ... = \int re^{-kr}\rho(r,\theta,\phi) C(r, \theta, \phi) \,d\theta d\phi dr.$$

Notice that changing coordinates introduced a $r^2$ factor.

This shows (unless I'm missing something!) that your integral doesn't diverge, if $\rho$ and $C$ are well-behaved.